# How can I add a randomly generated number to a variable that has already been set?

Tags: python

I have encountered a problem with some code I am doing to simulate a D&D (Dungeons and Dragons) campaign.

This is the code, but I am only experiencing difficulty with the most recent section.

I made code to roll a 4-sided dice and a 20-sided dice to divide the result of the 20-sided dice by the result of the 4-sided one, and then add this value to the preset value of 10 like so:

```
import math
strength = 10
dexterity = 10
wisdom = 10
intelligence = 10
constitution = 10
charisma = 10
attributes = ['strength', 'dexterity', 'wisdom', 'intelligence', 'constitution', 'charisma', strength, dexterity, wisdom, intelligence, constitution, charism]
import random
print("You have 6 attributes. Each level is 10. This is your chance to improve your stats.")
for iCount in range(0, 5):  
    print("Time to roll for", attributes[iCount]+".")
    roll = input("Press enter to roll a dice.")
    dice_result = random.randint(1,12)
    print("You roll a 12-sided dice and get", dice_result)
    roll = input("Press enter to roll another dice.") 
    dice_result2 = random.randint(1,4)
    print("You roll a 4-sided dice and get", dice_result2)
    attributes[iCount+6] = dice_result // dice_result2
    print("Your", attributes[iCount] ,"is", attributes[iCount+6])
import time
strength += 10
print("Your strength is", strength)
time.sleep(2)
dexterity += 10
print("Your dexterity is", dexterity)
time.sleep(2)
wisdom += 10    
print("Your wisdom is", wisdom)
time.sleep(2)
intelligence += 10
print("Your intelligence is", intelligence)
time.sleep(2)
constitution += 10
print("Your constitution is", constitution)
time.sleep(2)
charisma += 10
print("Your charisma is", charisma)
time.sleep(2)
```

There is no syntax error, although when my code runs I will get a low value for the first variable, and then a different that is the same for the rest of the remaining variables.

Comment: Updating values in a list will not update the variables you used to fill the list. So `strength` is still `10`, whatever you stored in the `attributes` list.

Comment: You should be using a *dictionary*, not separate variables. See the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

When you add the values of `strength`, `dexterity`, etc to your `attributes` array, you're just adding their current values.  Updating those values in the array does not update the original variables, and vice versa:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = [a]
>>> a = 6
>>> b
[5]
>>> b[0] = 7
>>> a
6
```

You should consider using a dictionary instead: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries